# Multivariate sparse Horner polynomials representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I'm reading [this](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/11541868_7) article that describes a way to represent multivariate polynomials in Horner form as part of a tactic to proof equalities on a field. I've gone through it several times and still I don't understand quite well the following part:

[image]

So my question is what is the expression $Q.X_{n-j+1}^{0} * \cdots * X_n^{0}$ suppose to mean? In principle, the injection polynomial should be the same polynomial with coefficients moved to higher exponents. But what is the $0$ super-index?

Also, for the last part how do I now from the expression $(PX \; P \; i \; Q)$ that I'm working with variable $X_n$? What about the other variables $X_j$?

Please, if you need any other details don't hesitate to comment.

**Edit**

I'm guessing that the polynomial $Q.X_{n-j+1}^{0} * \cdots * X_n^{0}$ is just the original polynomial multiplied by zero exponentiated variables .

I'm also guessing that the third construct is valid for all n so that we are constructing our polynomials in an onion-like shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation is greatly simplied in [this](http://www.russinoff.com/papers/shnf.pdf) article.